# Is it true that $G$ is cyclic of order $n$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. If there is $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that for every $g\in G$ we have $ng=0$  and $mg\neq 0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ with $m<n$, is it true that $G$ is cyclic of order $n$?

Comment: No. Consider the Klein four group.

Comment: You wrote «for every $g\in G$ we have $ng=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$» and this is very different from «there is some $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ such that for every $g\in G$ we have $ng=0$». My mind-reading machine tells me that this second option is what you *meant*. If this is right, you should correct the question.

Comment: Your mind reading machine is correct! That is what I meant. I've edited the question. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ is a group and $n\in\mathbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$ are such that

- for every $g\in G$ we have $ng=0$
- for every $g\in G$ and all for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ with $m<n$ we have $mg\neq 0$.

If $n>1$, then taking $g=1_G$, the identity element of $G$ and $m=1$ in the second condition we get a contradiction. It follows that we must have $n=1$ and then the first condition tells us that $G$ is the trivial group.

In particular, the group $G$ is cyclic of order $n$.

---

As noted in a comment, the answer above answers a question different from the one asked. Let's now deal with the question as it is asked. Suppose that $G$ is a group such that

- for every $g\in G$

  - there exists an $n\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ such that $ng=0$ and
  - for all $m\in\mathbb Z_{\geq0}$ with $m<n$ we have $mg\neq0$.

Then $G$ is not  cyclic. Indeed **every** finite group satifies this condition: if $g\in G$ then we can take $n$ to be the order of $g$.

Comment: The order of quantifiers matters.

Comment: Can one show that a group is cyclic of order $n$ by modifying these conditions?

Comment: There exist non-cyclic groups for which every element distinct from the identity has order $3$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Notice that the same is true if you place $3$ by $2$, and the smallest example then is the Klein four group, as mentioned by Vik78 a while ago!